# VLookup Application or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I wanted to ask waht am i doing wrong here ?? i want the VLookup to find if the ProjectID is already there , and if it is, I want it to skip the registering step and immediately go to Next Row_T to see the next row of data , whenever i start the error " Application-defined or object-defined error " comes up on the line :

```
 Repetition = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, ProjectID).Value, Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Range("A2:AS"), 1)
```

i don't know what is wrong , can you please help me ??

```
For Row_S = 2 To MAX_Row_S
 SourceYear = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, SOP).Value
     SourceYear = DatePart("yyyy", SourceYear)

     SourceCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, carmaker).Value
     SourceProject = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Project).Value
     SourceFamily = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Family).Value
     SourceStatus = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Status).Value
     SourceShare = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, Share).Value
     SourceCst = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, "A").Value
     SourcePID = Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, ProjectID).Value

     ' Take the data from NBG_Data_Region sheet to be Sourceared with each row of the NBG_Data_Source_Region sheet

    For Row_T = 2 To MAX_Row_T


    If Row_T >= MAX_Row_T Then
      Exit For
    End If


    'NBGMonth = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, SOP).Value
    'NBGMonth = DatePart("m", NBGMonth)

    NBGYear = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, SOP).Value
    NBGYear = DatePart("yyyy", NBGYear)

    NBGCarmaker = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, carmaker).Value
    NBGProject = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Project).Value
    NBGFamily = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Family).Value
    NBGStatus = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Status).Value
    NBGShare = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Share).Value
    NBGCst = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, "A").Value
    NBGPID = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, ProjectID).Value



 'Get the number of rows in Issue_SumofShares
'SoS = SumofShares
MAX_Row_inSoS = Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).UsedRange.RowS.Count

S = MAX_Row_inSoS

     Repetition = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, ProjectID).Value, Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Range("A2:AS"), 1)




 ' StatusBar Show

 Application.StatusBar = "VerifySumofShares. Progress: " & Row_S & " of " & MAX_Row_S

       'Check if any row with a SOP date in the previous or current years and if it is a D-IN or OPP is found and add it to the IssueSOP_Date sheet

       ' NAF 20161208
       'Test with Source of YEAR and MONTH
       ' If (NBGMonth = SourceMonth And NBGYear = SourceYear And SourceCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And SourceProject = NBGProject And SourceFamily = NBGFamily And SourceShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> SourceCst) Then
       ' With Year only
        If (NBGYear = SourceYear And SourceCarmaker = NBGCarmaker And SourceProject = NBGProject And SourceFamily = NBGFamily And SourceShare + NBGShare <> 1 And NBGCst <> SourceCst) Then
            If IsError(Repetition) = False Then
            GoTo Line1

              Else: GoTo Line2

              End If



       Line2:
              'Customization of the Issue_SumofShares sheet to show the NBG Data Row , Cst, SOP , Product, Responsible,Family , Carmaker , Share , Status and the GeoRegion of the data which the condition applies to


            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "A").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, ProjectID).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "B").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Customer).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "C").Value = GetMonthAndQuarter(Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, SOP).Value)
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "D").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Product).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "E").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Family).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "F").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Project).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "G").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, carmaker).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "H").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Share).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "I").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Responsible).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "K").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, Status).Value
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "L").Value = Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, "BO").Value
            ' Region As String
            Region = ""

            'Add any other GeoRegion which is also responsible in the recorded data


            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, "BC") Then
            Region = Region + "@EMEA"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, "BD") Then
            Region = Region + "@AMERICAS"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, "BE") Then
            Region = Region + "@GCSA"
            End If

            If Worksheets(NBG_DataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, "BF") Then
            Region = Region + "@JAPAN&KOREA"
            End If
            Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Cells(3 + Issue_SumofSharesCnt, "J").Value = Region





            'Count the number of the cases recorded

            Issue_SumofSharesCnt = Issue_SumofSharesCnt + 1

            'If there is no items , the Message to show

        ElseIf (Worksheets(NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_S, SOP).Value = "There are no items to show in this view.") Then

     End If

  Line1:

     Next Row_T

     Next Row_S
```

Comment: How did you declare `NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName` and `Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName`? Oh, also you're missing a row in `"A2:AS"` ...do you mean to like, `A2:A5`?  (Not `A2:A[letter "S"] `?)

Comment: The `Goto` statements are completely pointless.  They basically just manually mark out an `Else` block.

Comment: `Range("A2:AS")` is a 1004 error.  Is that a typo?

Comment: @BruceWayne here is how i declared them , and when i meant the letter S but it didn't work ( I don't know why) but now the error is "Type Mismatch" , please help 
/////Private Const NBG_SourceRegionDataWorksheetName = "NBG_Data_Source_Region"
////// Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName = "Issue_SumofShares" 


/////Repetition = Application.VLookup(Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName)‌​.Cells(Row_T, ProjectID).Value, Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Range("A3:A400"), 1)

Comment: (Can you please edit that into your original post, instead of a comment?)  Also, why have a variable name that's *longer* than the actual string you're storing in there? Just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Repetition = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
      Worksheets(NBG_RegionaDataWorksheetName).Cells(Row_T, ProjectID).Value, _
      Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName).Range("A2:AS"), 1)
```

This will throw a run-time error if the value being looked up is not found.  Safer to use this approach:

```
Repetition = Application.VLookup(...)
If Not IsError() Then
   'was found
Else
   'not found
End If
```

Omitting the `WorksheetFunction` means the function will instead return an error value which you can test for.  Also, you should always include the last argument `False`to VLookup unless you really want the default behavior.

As a side note, your code will be significantly more readable if you use variables to refer to your sheets instead repeating the full path every time:

```
Dim wsISOS As Worksheet
Set wsISOS = Worksheets(Issue_SumofSharesWorksheetName)
```

Comment: man something is wrong , all i want is if the Project ID is already in the Issue_SumofShares sheet (identical) that it skips the registering step and goes to NextRow_T , when i used ur code (which is really helpful) it skiped the registering step for all the rows , please help me